# Visual FoxPro - Table Grid

Tags: user-interface, grid, visual-foxpro

How can I achieve this kind of grid? What controls/tools I should use? Any idea?

[image]

This screen cast is from the [Baplie Viewer](http://www.geocities.ws/milatovicd/baplie.html) application. I guess it was done by the captain using visual foxpro while he was sailing.

**[Edit]**
It is ready-only and column widths will be fixed. It is a kind of reporting generated in a tabular format similar to Grid, but I think we cannot use the native Grid control.
And it may be needed to generate dynamically. I mean we would not be able to use shape tools, line tool, etc. in design time.

Comment: Not seeing actual controls, but I've seen similar via use of "FlexGrid" control...  However... are you able to stretch the column widths or are they fixed... big difference in how it might be implemented.

Comment: Column widths would be fixed.

Comment: Can the user "Edit" the data within the grid, or is it read-only

Comment: No, it is just for display. It is a kind of reporting.

Answer (score 0):

Is the grid editable? Or readonly?

A VFP grid control can take any of the VFP controls as the column control source. For example, the "Total" row may be two columns. The second column could contain another VFP grid as it's control source. While the first column is just a textbox or label.

Or, this grid could be readonly and created by using the Line or Shape controls, coloring their areas and using labels to represent the data.

If you are interested in using third party controls like this, I would recommend DBI-Technologies. They have a large selection of custom controls that work with VFP.

Comment: It is readonly. Please see my updated question. Where can I see DBI-Technologies.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a grid control, or a FoxPro control of any type.  (Or, at least, that's not the best way to get that effect.)  It's a webview control bound to an HTML web page, generated in the background and then displayed  most likely via a temporary file.

The easiest way to achieve the effect in a FoxPro application is to use the CUROSRTOXML function and a XSLT transformation.